# ggplot2: Centering stacked barplot on central category

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm creating a stacked barplot where I have 5 ordered categories for each bar - let's just call them 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. I want to center each bar around the middle value (3), in a similar format to how O'Connor et. al. did here.

[image]

I have the rest of the figure completed.

Here's an example of my data and what I have so far:

```
sampledata=data.frame(c(rep("category1",30),rep("category2",30),rep("category3",30)),round(runif(90,min=1,max=5)))
colnames(sampledata)=c("categories","values")

ggplot(data=sampledata,aes(x=categories,fill=factor(values)))+
  geom_bar(position="stack")+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="RdBu",direction=-1)+
  coord_flip()
```

I'm not sure how exactly to word this problem and searches so far have not been conclusive. Thanks for your help!

Comment: This blog link might be what you are after: http://rnotr.com/likert/ggplot/barometer/likert-plots/

Comment: You may want to look at [the likert package](https://rcompanion.org/handbook/E_03.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's set up your sample data differently:

```
set.seed(1001)
sampledata <- data.frame(category1 = sample(factor(1:5), 30, replace = TRUE),
                         category2 = sample(factor(1:5), 30, replace = TRUE),
                         category3 = sample(factor(1:5), 30, replace = TRUE))
```

Now it is in suitable form for use with the `likert` package.

```
library(likert)
plot(likert(sampledata))
```

[image]